# Double size in malloc()

Tags: c, malloc

What is the memory allocation if I double the size in malloc().

```
    struct node{
    int data;
    struct node*next;
    };
    void main(){
    //What if I place 2,3 or 4 times the size.What is the memory allocation looks like.What if I do something like 1.5 times or say 1.3 times
    struct node* a =(struct node *)malloc(2*sizeof(struct node)); 
//Moreover if I print this I get 8,if I am saying twice size,shouldn't I get 16 size(two nodes with 8 bytes each(4 byte of data and 4 byte of next))
printf("%d",sizeof(*a));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your question is unclear, I think you are confused about the `sizeof()` operator, it does not give you the allocated size of an object, but instead the size of it's type, in the case of arrays since they are of array type their size will be the size of the array in bytes.

This is a quote from the standard draft

> **6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**
>
> 2. The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>      expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>      the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.
> 3. The `_Alignof` operator yields the alignment requirement of its operand type. The
>      operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant. When applied to an array
>      type, the result is the alignment requirement of the element type.
> 4. When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or
>      `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1. When applied to an
>      operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. <sup>103)</sup> When applied to an operand that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of bytes in such an object, including internal and trailing padding.

Also, if you are working with c, don't cast `void *` to other pointer types, it's not necessary, if it's c++, then use `new` instead of `malloc()`.

The line

```
node *a = malloc(2 * sizeof(*a));
```

allocates enough space to hold two objects of type `node`, so you can use it whith index notation if you want like

```
a[0].data = 1;
a[1].data = 2;
```

but that doesn't mean that `a` is an array, this syntax is possible because it's equivalent using pointer arithmetic is

```
(*(a + 0)).data = 1;
(*(a + 1)).data = 1;
/* incrementa a by 1, and then dereference it -> a[1] */
```

where I suppose it's easier to see that `a` is not an array.

---

<sup>103)</sup><sub>When applied to a parameter declared to have array or function type, the sizeof operator yields the size of the adjusted (pointer) type (see 6.9.1).</sub>

Comment: "Unless"? I don't exactly understand that "unless": "...unless the object is an array, in which case it gives the size of the array in bytes." There's nothing exceptional in the behavior of `sizeof` with arrays. It simply gives the size of the array type in bytes, just like it does with all other types. Arrays don't stand out in any way here. So, why the "unless"?

Comment: @TobySpeight you are welcome to edit my answer, but `sizeof()` is intentionally with parentheses and `sizeof(*a)` is also intentionally with parentheses because I like to be consistent and when you are forced to use a type name you can't omit parentheses. Please don't do edits that add words to the answer or conflict with the posrter intention, leave comments to suggest such deep changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `malloc(2*sizeof(struct node))` you are allocating a memory block that can store two `struct node`s right next to each other. If you say 3, or 4, etc., that is how many `struct node`s you can then put next to each other in this bigger allocation.

If you say something like `malloc(1.5*sizeof(struct node))` then you should get a compiler warning or error about passing a `double` to a function (`malloc`) that requires an `int`, because `1.5*sizeof(struct node)` is `1.5` multiplied by an integer, which is a double.

`sizeof(*a)` actually depends not on your `malloc` call, but on only the size, in memory, of a single instance of a `struct node`. This size is comprised of the actual fields in your struct, along with any padding or extra bytes your implementation of the C compiler wants.

Comment: The question is not about size of a pointer (`sizeof a`) but about the size of its referent (`sizeof *a`).  Everything else above is correct.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the correction! I really need to read questions more closely.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof *a` won't change - that's the size of the **element** you get when you dereference `a`.  Since `*a` is a `struct node`, then `sizeof *a`==`sizeof (struct node)`.

BTW, don't cast the result of `malloc()` - instead, `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything :

- `main()` should return `int`, not `void`.
- Do not cast the result of `malloc()`.
- Please indent your code to improve readability.
- The format specifier for size_t is `%zu`, not `%d`.

Now, let's get to your questions :

> What if I place 2,3 or 4 times the size.What is the memory allocation looks like.What if I do something like 1.5 times or say 1.3 times

Well you're allocating enough for 2/3/4 of these structs, packet together in an array. You can access them using array indexing notation :

```
// Accesses the second struct
a[1].data = 47;
```

> Moreover if I print this I get 8,if I am saying twice size,shouldn't I get 16 size(two nodes with 8 bytes each(4 byte of data and 4 byte of next))

`sizeof` is a compile-time* operator. It measures the size of the type you pass to it. `a` is a pointer to a `struct node`, so `*a` is a `struct node`, and that's what you're measuring. If you want to keep track of the length of your dynamically-allocated array, you need to do it by hand.

*Unless its operand is a VLA. But nobody likes VLAs.

Comment: Why should I not add cast to malloc. Correct me : if I don't put it I would only get specified free memory space.How would then I do something like a->data=3....?

Comment: @NamanAgarwal if you don't put it, you'll have no chance of getting it wrong, and the compiler will happily convert it to the type of `a` like the smart guys who wrote the standard intended.